# CLion regex replace with pattern with found string

Tags: regex, clion

I want to replace string `Sleep(*any value*)`
to `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(*found value*))`.

For example, from `Sleep(5000)`
to `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000))`.

I tried to do this:
from regex: `Sleep\((.*)\)` to regex: `std::this_thread::sleep_for\(std::chrono::milliseconds\(\1\)\)`

It works in notepad++, but not in CLion. Why?
`\1, \2, \3, ..., \n` works only in notepad++?

Comment: Are you doing the replacement in an IDE/text editor? If so, what does the question have to do with c++?

Comment: `CLion` probably does not use the same regex engine as `notepad++` or it doesn't use the same interface to the regex engine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, can I do it with CLion like with notepad++? Maybe some other pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CLion, it is not `\n`, but `$n` to reference capture groups.

See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference